# acts_as_revisable 'loses' previous models created before migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following the standard, regular post sample app.

I created some posts then decided to introduce `acts_as_revisable`

After following the instructions at http://github.com/rich/acts_as_revisable I see that the previous posts are not appearing in the `Post.all` call.

However, if I use the console and do `Post.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM Post WHERE ID=1")` the post shows up.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with the migration.

the version i have is:

```
add_column :companies, :revisable_is_current, :boolean => 1
```

But it should be

```
add_column :companies, :revisable_is_current, :boolean => 't'
```